# MySQL query optimization: Multiple SELECT IN to LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I usually go with the `join` approach but in this case I am a bit confused. I am not even sure that it is possible at all. I wonder if the following query can be converted to a `left join` query instead of the multiple `select in` used:

```
select 
   users.id, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.description, users.email 
from users 
where id in (
     select assigned.id_user from assigned where id_project in (
            select assigned.id_project from assigned where id_user = 1
                                                               )
            ) 
   or id in (
     select projects.id_user from projects where projects.id in (
            select assigned.id_project from assigned where id_user = 1
                                                                )
            )
```

This query returns the correct result set. However, I guess the repetition of the query that selects `assigned.id_project` is a waste.

Comment: use joins y are you using subquries

Comment: @ArunKillu because I am not sure what the relations between the tables would be :)

Comment: I don't think this can be done with joins since you join on two different tables with OR clause.

Comment: Of course it can be done with joins.

Comment: In what way specifically does that seem to you a waste? Are you thinking about eliminating the need to evaluate the same selection twice? Or does that have more to do with code duplication?

Comment: @AndriyM because the same code is executed twice, I guess there is another way to do it so that it doesn't have to select twice the same data.

Comment: Selecting the same data twice isn't the problem. The real issue is that internally it is more complex to merge those resultsets of subqueries, while it is easier most of the time to do simple joins. Especially when using `in` this is the case. The query would be a lot faster probably if you rewrote it to using `exists` instead of `in`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both subqueries have a condition where assigned.id_user = 1, I start with that query. Let's call that assignment(s) the 'leading assignment'.

Then join the rest, using left joins for the 'optional' tables.
Use an inner join on `user` that matches either users of assignments linked to the leading assignment or users of projects linked to the leading project.

I use distinct, because I assumen you'd want each user once, event if they have an assignment and a project (or multiple projects).

```
select distinct
  u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.description, u.email 
from 
  assigned a
  left join assigned ap on ap.id_project = a.id_project
  left join projects p on p.id = a.id_project
  inner join users u on u.id = ap.id_user or u.id = p.id_user
where
  a.id_user = 1
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to motivate? Guessing that it won't work, or have you actually tried?

Comment: I didn't downvote it. Just tried it, it returnes the first part but it fails to return the results that my query's second part does.

Comment: +1 Good query, wondering why this is downvoted.  @Andrew: can you add some example data, so we can see which rows are not returned and why?

Comment: This will produce a worse execution plan than using the semi joins in the question since the need to sort all the columns in the select to perform the Distinct operation.

Comment: @Magnus: the `distinct` is missing from the original query.  Of course adding it introduces extra work, but it also improves the result set.

Comment: @Magnus MySQL performs really badly when using `in`. Distinct is relatively easy.

Comment: @GolezTrol I guess you made some changes in between. At first it only returned the results for the first part of my query, not it returns the correct result set

Comment: @Andrew, That's true, sorry about that. At first I use `p.id_project = a.id_project` in the join, instead of `p_id`. If the query didn't fail then, apparently you have both `id` and `id_project` in your projects table, but with a different value.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes, you're right. That's because I designed the projects table to accept parent projects in the future :)

Comment: @GolezTrol are you sure? It is the opposite for all other databases I know. Comparing your execution plan to the one in the question using MS SQL server, yours is much worse.

Comment: I would remove `DISTINCT` and add `GROUP BY u.id` The results will be the same and efficiency better (or equal, not worse anyway).

Answer (score 4):

You could start with the project assignments of user 1 `a1`. Then find all assignments of other people to those projects `a2`, and the user in the project table `p`.  The users you are looking for are then in either `a2` or `p`.  I added distinct to remove users who can be reached in both ways.

```
select  distinct u.*
from    assigned a1
left join    
        assigned a2
on      a1.id_project = a2.id_project
left join
        project p
on      a1.id_project = p.id
join    user u
on      u.id = a2.id_user
        or u.id = p.id_user
where   a1.id_user = 1
```

Comment: Andomar even made the same typo as I did at first, using the table `user` instead of `users`. Makes you wonder.... ;-)

Comment: @GolezTrol I fixed that. That wasn't the reason why it didn't work, that was something that is easily fixable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative way to get rid of the repetition:

```
SELECT
  users.id,
  users.first_name,
  users.last_name,
  users.description,
  users.email 
FROM users
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT up.id_user
  FROM (
    SELECT id_user, id_project FROM assigned
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id_user, id         FROM projects
  ) up
  INNER JOIN assigned a
    ON a.id_project = up.id_project
  WHERE a.id_user = 1
)
;
```

That is, the `assigned` table's pairs of `id_user, id_project` are UNIONed with those of `projects`. The resulting set is then joined with the `user_id = 1` projects to obtain the list of all users who share the projects with the ID 1 user. And now it only remains to retrieve the details for those users, which in this case is done in the same way as in your query, i.e. using an IN clause.

I'm sorry to say that I don't have MySQL to thoroughly test the performance of this query and so cannot be quite sure if it is in any way better or worse than your original query or than the one suggested both [by @GolezTrol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13099263/297408) and [by @Andomar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13099330/297408). Generally I tend to agree with [@GolezTrol's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099183/mysql-query-optimization-multiple-select-in-to-left-join/13100479#comment17803367_13099183) that a query with simple (semi- or whatever-) joins and repetitive parts might turn out more efficient than an equivalent sophisticated query that doesn't have repetitions. In the end, however, it is testing that must reveal the final answer for you.